# Can anyone explain about Microsoft's CDN?

Tags: asp.net, cdn

I understand I can get my script files from their CDN for my asp.net application, but what's the best way to implement this? It says that requests will be redirected to the CDN if I enable the property of the script manager, but what does that actually mean?

At the moment we have lots of pages which reference JQuery, some reference it from google, some reference it locally. Do I change all these references to point to Microsoft? How does the CDN property of the scriptmanager affect things then?

Is there a global solution I can use?

Comment: I had some problems with Microsoft's CDN, sometimes it didn't respond, and this caused my page to load very slow. Also they don't update it that quickly (when a new release comes out). I only use Google's CDN, also given @Moo's caching reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Scott Guthrie explains it nicely on his [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/announcing-the-microsoft-ajax-cdn.aspx).

Basically, if you set EnableCdn="true" on your ScriptManager block in ASP.net 4.0, for any standard Javascript include file that ASP.Net normally brings in, it will instead get it from the Microsoft CDN.  This includes libraries such as the client site components of the ScriptManager et al

You also have the option of supplying CDN urls for JQuery et al directly - these will not be handled by the above flag.

Whether or not you switch from Googles CDN to Microsofts is one of preference - Google includes theirs in many of their Javascript enabled sites, which gives you a huge chance of having their file already cached, while Microsoft similarly include theirs on their sites, but their sites may have less exposure than Googles.

It's a toss up, go with what you want, but personally I don't reference locally any longer unless its an Intranet app, uses a custom JQuery, or has an offline requirement.